# Get field values in record.js

Tags: sugarcrm

I override the record view, by creating in custom/modules/myModule/clients/base/views/record/record.js  this file record.js. I want to get the value of a field for the current object  and I use this.model.get('duration'), but I get nothing.The only field available is "id". How can I retrieve the values for others fileds?

Answer (score 1):

When the record.js script is initially called, the model won't have fully loaded, so the only available field with be the id.

Your best bet is probably to override the _renderHtml function; by the the time the view is being rendered all the model details will have fully loaded:

```
_renderHtml: function() {
    // custom code involving this.model.get('duration')

    // call parent
    app.view.View.prototype._renderHtml.call(this);
}
```

Note that you may find _renderHtml is called multiple times, sometines before the model is fully loaded.  This is just a quirk of Sugar so it may be best to add a check in your code:

```
if (this.model.get('duration')) {
    // custom code involving this.model.get('duration')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget that `app.model.get('myfield')` only delivers the right content (from this field) when your field is already displayed in detailview - else you will get "undefined"!

So you

1. Have to call the rest api (rest/v10/yourmodel/yourid) - than you
   have all the values available
2. Display your fields (even you dont want to) to be able to use it in `app.model.get('yourfield')`, an alternative you could append your record.js (after rendering) with  `$('div [data-name="yourfield"]').hide();`

I know this question is quite old already (but if someone else run into this he could find this useful).